# Play 2.0 - Java: Adding selected value to @select field

Tags: java, select, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to the play framework (I use the Java version). I am looking for a solution to add a selected="selected" to a  field. My code:

```
@select(settingsForm("projectManager"), options(projectManagers), '_label -> "Project manager" )
```

The HTML result looks like:

```
<select id="projectManager" name="projectManager">   
    <option value="222">Henk</option>
    <option value="96">Geert</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone know the scale argument of the @select field to add the select=selected to the html? The result i am looking for looks like:

```
<select id="projectManager" name="projectManager">   
    <option value="222">Henk</option>
    <option value="96" select="selected">Geert</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the web for some time, my thought went to the sample projects. The answer was there, right in front of me. Creating only the form with a view is not enough! To make this clearer, just look at the computer-database example. To create a empty field, you just pass a Form object to to the view:

```
Controller:
public static Result create() {
    Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class);
    return ok(
        createForm.render(computerForm)
    );
}

View:
@inputText(computerForm("name"), '_label -> "Computer name")
@inputText(computerForm("introduced"), '_label -> "Introduced date")
@inputText(computerForm("discontinued"), '_label -> "Discontinued date")
```

If you want the Form to be filled, you need to pass data to that Form. As the example shows:

```
 public static Result edit(Long id) {
    Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class).fill(
        Computer.find.byId(id)
    );
    return ok(
        editForm.render(id, computerForm)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In scala, I know the following code in the controller will make `96` selected

```
settingsForm.bind( Map("projectManager" -> "96"))
```

In Java it should work the same way from my guess.

Comment: Trouble with using bind is that it will cause error messages for any required fields whose values you have not supplied. This seems to be the neatest Scala solution: @select(settingsForm("projectManager").copy(value=Some("96")),
options(projectManagers), '_label -> "Project manager" )

Comment: Yep... @Joffer is right on the money. This approach solves one problem but causes another.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know an answer, but according to [source code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html) you must modify your *projectManagers* by someway.

Also, you may try to ask this question in [Play-Framework group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework).

Maybe it will be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that projectManager is some kind of relation. Then you could try:

```
@select(
    settingsForm("projectManager.id"), 
    options(projectManagers), 
    '_label -> "Project manager" 
)
```

@see:[similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294037/how-do-you-update-manytoone-field-in-a-form/10295287#10295287)

Comment: Projectmanager is a Hashmap with key value -> id, name. I do pull this list from another program. My model just contains a String (that is the id):

 @Column(name = "project_manager"
 private String projectManager; //Can be like '96'

What i want is when the projectManager is filled, the selected value of the select box is selected by the projectManager value. Say projectManager is '96', therefore 'Geert' will be selected